# Wave function in a semi infinite line

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hamiltonian, normalization

How to normalize the wave function of a particle in a semi-infinite 1D interval $x\in [0, \infty],$ with boundary condition $\varphi(0)=0\,?$ Hamiltonian is $H=P^2/2M$  and wave function $\varphi(x)=C\sin(xp/ \hbar)\,.$

Comment: @ValterMoretti I suppose because of lack of research effort. All current close votes are with this reason.

Comment: @ValterMoretti "off topic because..." to be precise. If you click there, you'll be presented the details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP didn't show sufficient research efforts.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I understand. Do you think I should remove my answer?

Comment: I'm not still competent enough @Valter to judge the content of your post. However, in general, when you answer such post which shows little to no research efforts at all, keep in mind not to completely answer the question and provide complete solution; just show OP the _conceptual_ path; that's it; after-all we are not homework-solving service albeit we have no problem in helping OP to  have a clearer insight on the concerned concept(s).

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Your competence does not matter here. I am just referring to the fact that my answer, correct or not,  is *complete* thus leaving no further efforts to the OP. The policy regarding the questions is clear to me, there are reasons to close this question. But what about the policy about too explicit  answers like mine?

Comment: @ValterMoretti: As I said, you shouldn't provide a complete answer to homework problems. [Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest, and if a solution complete enough to be copied verbatim and handed in is given immediately, it will encourage more people to use the site as a free homework service.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution)

Comment: I helped close the question. I tried to delete my answer, but it is too late. Sorry "to close the stable door after the horse has bolted"

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Excerpt from discussion with ACM at the chat; [Valter took a sensible interpretation of what that was supposed to mean and ran with it...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32660888#32660888); [His answer would still be a good answer if the question was edited to "Is there a meaningful notion of normalization for this non-normalizable function?"...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32660910#32660910). Finally, I very much respect your decision on your post.

Comment: Well, I think the question was definitely homework and therefore I would like to keep deleted my answer... otherwise the SE "homework policy" (policy which I do support) would have a little value. Thank you for having clarified the point.

Comment: Sure, @ValterMoretti; that's my job as an editor, reviewer and as a fellow community comrade here  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a state which cannot be properly normalized, it is a plane-wave solution. You cannot find a normalization $C$ such that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm d x \, |\phi(x)|^2 = 1 \,.$$

You could make a wave packet which is Gaussian curve in momentum space. Then your wave function would be a linear combination of your momentum eigenstates. But you cannot really normalize the plane wave.

Answer (score 0):

The wave function:

$$\varphi(x)=C\sin(xp/ \hbar)$$

Isn't normalisable. Just try it:

$$1=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}[\varphi^*(x)\varphi(x)]dx=C^2\int_0^{+\infty}\big(\sin(xp/ \hbar)\big)^2dx=C^2\Bigg[\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\hbar}{4p}\sin(2xp/ \hbar)\Bigg]_0^{+\infty}$$

It has no Real solution for $C$.